# Touch ID not showing StoreKit

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, touch-id

I'm using StoreKit for processing In-App purchases, which works perfectly. 
My only issue which I couldn't find a solution online is: 
In other apps when trying to do an IAP, I'm asked for Touch ID (so it's not my device set up wrong or so) while in my App it always asks for password. 
How can I get Touch ID to work for authentication with iTunes?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you tested it on a physical device, not on a simulator, right? If you've tested it on the simulator, the touch ID won't work...

Comment: Sure, iPhone 6S. My mac has no Touch ID 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, 
So I'm not sure if this is always the case but in the AppStore version of my App you can actually use Touch ID.
Maybe Touch ID is just not supported when developing... Still a bit confusing that they have you release your App without being sure if Touch ID is going to work :/

Comment: so when i release the app the touchID in-app purchase will work ? , do u find a solution how to check if its working in development

Comment: Hello Jack, I can’t tell you for sure but in my case it was like that, yes. Didn’t change anything and Touch ID worked just fine. I didn’t find a solution to get it working while in development!